# Bash script not finding files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ffmpeg

I am writing a simple script to iterate over all the m4a files in a folder and encode them to mp3. I want to do the encoding of the files in different threads to increase the speed of execution and take advantage of all the cores in my PC, so I am sending the tasks to background, please advice me if this is the right approach.
Anyway, I am getting a *No such file or direcory* error for every single file that I want to encode, even though the file is there; and the funny thing is that if I copy the exact same instruction to a terminal, it will be executed correctly. Can you please help me to find out what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

```
#!/bin/bash

function encode {
    echo "<<<<<<<<<<< encode >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"
    cd "$1"
    find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 | while read f
    do
        if [ -f "${f}" ]
        then
            if [ ${f: -4} == ".m4a" ]
            then
                if [ ! -d "converted" ]
                then
                    mkdir converted
                fi
                newPath="${f%m4a}mp3"
                echo "ffmpeg -i \""$f"\" -ac 2 -b:a 320k -y \""$newPath"\" </dev/null >/dev/null &"
                ffmpeg -i \""$f"\" -ac 2 -b:a 320k -y \""$newPath"\" </dev/null >/dev/null &
            fi
        elif [ -d "${f}" ]
        then
            echo "folder $f"
            encode "$f"
        fi
    done
}


encode "$1"
```

Comment: You have too many quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you allude to is that you are adding literal quotes to the name of the file; `"$f"` is sufficient to pass the value of `$f` as-is to the `ffmpeg` command. You don't need to use `find` to iterate over the immediate contents of a directory; just use a glob with a `for` loop (which also avoids the need to stop `ffmpeg` from reading from standard input).

More subtlely, you also need `encode` to restore the original working directory before it returns, so that recursive calls don't "unexpectedly" change the working directory while iterating over the current directory. `pushd` (instead of `cd`) and `popd` make this simple.

```
encode () {
  echo "<<<<<<<<<<< encode >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"
  pushd "$1"
  for f in *; do
    if [ -d "$f" ]; then
      encode "$f"
    elif [[ $f = *.m4a ]]; then
      mkdir -p converted
      newPath="${f%.m4a}.mp3"
      ffmpeg -i "$f" -ac 2 -b:a 320k -y "$newPath" > /dev/null &
    fi
  done
  popd
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked like a charm. Just added the "converted" directory to the encoded path so it is stored in the new created folder.